# How to parse XML data to retrieve child nodes value?

Tags: c#, xml, silverlight, xml-parsing

I do have a xml file located at  : http://api.wunderground.com/api/adaebe40743a9ca6/geolookup/conditions/forecast/q/India/Pilani.xml

Now i want to fetch values at `temp_c, relative_humidity, wind_string`.

For that i have created a class WeatherReader.cs as

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Ink;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Xml;

namespace CNGS
{
    public class WeatherReader
    {   public int Temp;
        public string Humidity;
        public string Wind;
        public string place;

        private void PopulateWeatherData()
        {
            XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create("http://api.wunderground.com/api/adaebe40743a9ca6/geolookup/conditions/forecast/q/India/Pilani.xml");

            reader.MoveToContent();            

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                if (reader.LocalName == "temp_c")
                {
                    Temp = Convert.ToInt32(reader.Value);
                }
if (reader.LocalName == "relative_humidity")
                {
                    Humidity=reader.Value;
                }
if (reader.LocalName == "wind_string")
                {
                    Wind= reader.Value;
                }


            }

            reader.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

**Is it correct, will it fetch the required values ?**

Now since i want to show this information in a silverlight page. I tried to create an object of class weatherreader as

```
WeatherReader Weath = new WeatherReader();
```

*but i don't know how to fetch the Temp, Wind values etc?  nothing like `int tmp = Weath.Temp` is working.*

Please Help

I want to fetch the weather data and then use it in silverlight controls on MainPage, to show Live Weather Report.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No that's not how you would use an `XmlReader` to read the document.  It's a lot more complicated than that, in fact... too complicated.

You're better off using LINQ to XML for this as it will be much simpler.

```
var xml = "http://api.wunderground.com/api/adaebe40743a9ca6/geolookup/conditions/forecast/q/India/Pilani.xml";
var doc = XDocument.Load(xml);
var currentObservation = doc.Element("response").Element("current_observation");
var temp = (int)currentObservation.Element("temp_c");
var humidity = (string)currentObservation.Element("relative_humidity");
var wind = (string)currentObservation.Element("wind_string");
```

If you wanted to use an `XmlReader`, then you'd have to do something like this:

```
var xml = "http://api.wunderground.com/api/adaebe40743a9ca6/geolookup/conditions/forecast/q/India/Pilani.xml";
using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(xml))
{
    var temp = default(int);
    var humidity = default(string);
    var wind = default(string);

    string elementName = null;
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        switch (reader.NodeType)
        {
        case XmlNodeType.Element:
            elementName = reader.Name;
            break;
        case XmlNodeType.Text:
            switch (elementName)
            {
            case "temp_c":
                temp = reader.ReadContentAsInt();
                break;
            case "relative_humidity":
                humidity = reader.ReadContentAsString();
                break;
            case "wind_string":
                wind = reader.ReadContentAsString();
                break;
            }
            elementName = null;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Getting Error : "Cannot open 'http://api.wunderground.com/api/adaebe40743a9ca6/geolookup/conditions/forecast/q/India/Pilani.xml'. The Uri parameter must be a relative path pointing to content inside the Silverlight application's XAP package. If you need to load content from an arbitrary Uri, please see the documentation on Loading XML content using WebClient/HttpWebRequest."

Answer (score 0):

This would be my version:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("http://api.wunderground.com/api/adaebe40743a9ca6/geolookup/conditions/forecast/q/India/Pilani.xml");
var v = from d in doc.Element("response").Elements("current_observation") select new { Temp = d.Element("temp_c").Value, Humedity = d.Element("relative_humidity").Value, Wind = d.Element("wind_string").Value };
foreach (var c in v)
{
    Console.WriteLine(c.Temp);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this it is not the most elegant solution but should work.

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml;

namespace CNGS
{
    public class WeatherReader
    {
        public int Temp;
        public string Humidity;
        public string Wind;
        public string place;

        public void PopulateWeatherData()
        {
            XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create("http://api.wunderground.com/api/adaebe40743a9ca6/geolookup/conditions/forecast/q/India/Pilani.xml");

            bool IsNextTemp = false;
            bool IsHumidityTemp = false;
            bool IsWindTemp = false;

            reader.MoveToContent();

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                switch (reader.NodeType)
                {
                    case XmlNodeType.Element: // The node is an element.
                        if (reader.Name == "temp_c")
                        {
                            IsHumidityTemp = false;
                            IsWindTemp = false;
                            IsNextTemp = true;
                        }
                        else if (reader.Name == "relative_humidity")
                        {
                            IsHumidityTemp = true;
                            IsWindTemp = false;
                            IsNextTemp = false;
                        }
                        else if (reader.Name == "wind_string")
                        {
                            IsHumidityTemp = false;
                            IsWindTemp = true;
                            IsNextTemp = false;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            IsHumidityTemp = false;
                            IsWindTemp = false;
                            IsNextTemp = false;
                        }
                        break;
                    case XmlNodeType.Text: //Display the text in each element.
                        if (IsHumidityTemp)
                            this.Humidity = reader.Value;
                        else if (IsNextTemp)
                            this.Temp = int.Parse(reader.Value);
                        else if (IsWindTemp)
                            this.Wind = reader.Value;
                        break;
                }

            }

            reader.Close();
        }
    }
}
```